# Dovecot problems wit SSL Cert: Verify return code: 2 (unable to get issuer certificate)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, dovecot

sry for that, but i am a newcomer at ssl and what do i wrong? i try to change the dovecot imap login to imaps but something goes wrong with the ssl cert check. The ssl cert works for the https apache server and its the same what i try to use for dovecot. i tried to understand the answere from dave thomson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108886/openssl-s-client-error-verify-errornum-2unable-to-get-issuer-certificate but it's hard for an newcomer. maybe you have an easier way. thx and br

```
openssl s_client -connect <my-domain>:993 -servername <my-domain> -CAfile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert_2021.ca-bundle
```

output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
verify error:num=2:unable to get issuer certificate
issuer= C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Comodo CA Limited, CN = AAA Certificate Services
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
issuer= C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = <my-domain>
issuer= C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
0 s:CN = <my-domain>
i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...gJaprVUs
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = <my-domain>

issuer=C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2192 bytes and written 397 bytes
Verification error: unable to get issuer certificate
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 2 (unable to get issuer certificate)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1.3
Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Session-ID: 3B8DCD9A603FF577C1E77F40C5D3BCE2B9BAE026EF430566359B0D82353CE1E5
Session-ID-ctx:
Resumption PSK: 69E09...34D1
PSK identity: None
PSK identity hint: None
SRP username: None
TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
TLS session ticket:
0000 - 97 86 ca 30 d9 1e 13 95-51 b3 06 87 9d 9f fe ec   ...0....Q.......
...
00d0 - 26 69 ba 7b 58 58 2c da-18 90 c9 8b 9f e2 3f be   &i.{XX,.......?.

Start Time: 1651046361
Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
Verify return code: 2 (unable to get issuer certificate)
Extended master secret: no
Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
Protocol  : TLSv1.3
Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Session-ID: F834...EE6E
Session-ID-ctx:
Resumption PSK: A6FBE...23BF
PSK identity: None
PSK identity hint: None
SRP username: None
TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
TLS session ticket:
0000 - 97 86 ca 30 d9 1e 13 95-51 b3 06 87 9d 9f fe ec   ...0....Q.......
...
00d0 - a9 74 d9 44 c8 40 43 11-48 32 1e e2 2a 8f b9 bb   .t.D.@C.H2..*...

Start Time: 1651046361
Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
Verify return code: 2 (unable to get issuer certificate)
Extended master secret: no
Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE LITERAL+ AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot (Raspbian) ready.
* BYE Disconnected for inactivity.
closed
```

for other tries

```
openssl s_client -connect <my-domain>:993 -servername <my-domain> -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ | grep 'returncode'
```

i get the same output:

```
depth=0 CN = <my-domain>
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
...
..
.
Start Time: 1651049986
Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
Extended master secret: no
Max Early Data: 0
```

my

```
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf
```

has the minimum cfg

```
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/apache2/ssl/cert_2021.crt
ssl_key = </etc/apache2/ssl/cert_2021.key
ssl_client_ca_file = /etc/apache2/ssl/cert_2021.ca-bundle
ssl_dh = </usr/share/dovecot/dh.pem
```

### **UPDATE:**

After your input **anx** i throw all the stuff in on single file. mean the crt, key and ca-bundle information nicely and smooth with copy + paste. saved unter `/etc/dovecot/private` without any symlink. under `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf` i set

```
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/all_certs_in_one.txt
#ssl_client_ca_file = /etc/apache2/ssl/es_2021.ca-bundle
```

and i tried the command

```
openssl s_client -showcerts 6-connect <my-domain>:993 -servername <my-domain>
```

i get that output, what is definitly more then the last one...

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 
322 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

### **UPDATE - with half SOLUTION**

nano mkcert.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# Generates a self-signed certificate.
# Edit dovecot-openssl.cnf before running this.
umask 077
OPENSSL=${OPENSSL-openssl}
SSLDIR=${SSLDIR-/etc/ssl}
OPENSSLCONFIG=${OPENSSLCONFIG-dovecot-openssl.cnf}

CERTDIR=$SSLDIR/certs
KEYDIR=$SSLDIR/private

CERTFILE=$CERTDIR/dovecot.pem
KEYFILE=$KEYDIR/dovecot.pem

if [ ! -d $CERTDIR ]; then
  echo "$SSLDIR/certs directory doesn't exist"
  exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d $KEYDIR ]; then
  echo "$SSLDIR/private directory doesn't exist"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -f $CERTFILE ]; then
  echo "$CERTFILE already exists, won't overwrite"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -f $KEYFILE ]; then
  echo "$KEYFILE already exists, won't overwrite"
  exit 1
fi

$OPENSSL req -new -x509 -nodes -config $OPENSSLCONFIG -out $CERTFILE -keyout $KEYFILE -days 3650 || exit 2
chmod 0600 $KEYFILE
echo
$OPENSSL x509 -subject -fingerprint -noout -in $CERTFILE || exit 2
```

nano dovecot-openssl.cnf

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
encrypt_key = yes
distinguished_name = req_dn
x509_extensions = cert_type
prompt = no

[ req_dn ]
# country (2 letter code)
#C=FI

# State or Province Name (full name)
#ST=

# Locality Name (eg. city)
#L=Helsinki

# Organization (eg. company)
O=<MY FIRM NAME>

# Organizational Unit Name (eg. section)
OU=IMAP server

# Common Name (*.example.com is also possible)
CN=mail.<YOUR DOMAIN NAME>

# E-mail contact support@example.com 
emailAddress=support@<YOUR DOMAIN NAME>

[ cert_type ]
nsCertType = server
```

create symlinks:

```
ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot_pem_sym.pem
ln -s /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot_pem_sym.key
```

nano /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf

```
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot_pem_sym.pem
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot_pem_sym.key
#ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
#ssl_client_ca_file =
#ssl_dh = </usr/share/dovecot/dh.pem
```

restart

```
systemctl restart dovecot
```

test

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <YOUR mail.DOMAIN>:993 -servername <YOUR mail.DOMAIN>
```

errorcode is

```
Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
```

but thats better then nothing =/ my apache cert doenst works but yeah. seams that we cant have everything working =(

btw. dont forget to set in outlook as example @cfg `method` to `SSL/TLS` not authomatic

Comment: Most probably your certificate file is missing the other certificates from the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You likely used the `ssl_client_ca_file` setting in error.** It is used when Dovecot makes outgoing connections in a *client* role (in case, say, it is proxying to MTA/IMAP destination where the systems default CA is inappropriate). This is completely separate from configuration of Dovecot handling incoming connections in a *server* role, such as providing IMAP service via TLS.

**Leave that unset, and instead [concatenate your server and intermediate certificates](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/dovecot_ssl_configuration/#chained-ssl-certificates) into one combined file to be used in `ssl_cert=</path/to/file`.**

Mind the order, in your case I believe that would be your server certificate, then *Sectigo*, then *Usertrust*. As you are currently pointing to apache2-used files, take care not to modify files you have configured elsewhere (with the expectation that they only contain either server cert or chain).

Comment: hi. first thx for your input i tried something (see UPDATE above) but now i got other kind of error. i cant see what i do wrong. for any input i will thx a lot. the outlook login on port 993 goes hand in hand with that working cert right? btw. if i use the ubuntu standarf snakeoil certs i get an good output but the outlook login still doenst works. the auth- error does not exist for the login try